# Color data items in a pandas dataframe based on value

Tags: python, pandas, visualization

I have a dataframe with some data (names, amount_x, amount_y and "diff" column which subtracts amount X and Y.

I would like to color the cells, where "diff" is a positive number (and make them green) and where it is negative, make it red)?

Is this possible?

Comment: There's no easy way to do this. You could probably get creative in using to_html method, assigning classes to pos/neg values, then using some css?

Comment: how large is your

Answer (score 5):

*Starting from Pandas version 0.17.1*

You can use ***style.applymap*** with this kind of line

```
df.style.applymap(color, subset=['diff'])
```

More infos and example here : 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html

Answer (score 1):

Have not tried the styling in pandas but, one could give python wrapper for ggplot(*https://github.com/yhat/ggpy*) a try,

```
# One might get some dependency errors in-regards to pandas-timeseries 
# module and statsmodels
# if that happens try, pip install --upgrade statsmodels 

sudo pip install ggplot
# Assuming one has a dataframe then,
from ggplot import *
# internally, it will figure out the unique values for VariableC and 
# define a color change automatically
ggplot(aes(x='variableA', y='variableB', color='VariableC'), 
        data=data_df) + geom_point()
```

Hopefully, that was helpful ...